# solution of $\bar{z}=\xi z$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Does $\bar{z}=\xi z$ has solution in $z$ (complex number) for all values of $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$?

I was trying to use normal method but its coming quite complicated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you elaborate a bit and tell us what you have done?

Comment: Does $z=0$ count?

Comment: it doesn't count, I meant nonzero solutions.

Comment: What do you think of the equation $\bar z=2z$? Specifically, in the context of absolute values?

Answer (score 1):

First, for *any* $\;\xi\in\Bbb C\;,\;\;z=0\;$ is a solution to $\;\overline z=\xi z\;$. Now, if we want non-zero solutions to this equation, we get that

$$\overline z=\xi z\implies |z|=|\xi|\,|z|\stackrel{\text{since}\;z\neq 0}\iff |\xi|=1\;$$

Thus, the answer to question in the first line of your post is *yes, since* $\;z=0\;$ *does the job* , and if we consider only $\;z\neq 0\iff z\in\Bbb C^*\;$, the answer then is *no, as only the complex elements* $\;\xi\in S^1=\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;\;|z|=1\}\;$ *have a chance to solve the given equation* .

**Added on request:** If $\;\xi=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\in S^1\;$, putting $\;z=r(\cos t+i\sin t)\;$ we get

$$\overline z=r(\cos t-i\sin t)=r\left(\cos\theta\cos t-\sin\theta\sin t+(\cos\theta\sin t+\sin\theta\cos t)i\right)\implies$$

$$\cos t-i\sin t=\cos(t+\theta)+i\sin(t+\theta)$$

This gives us two equations:

$$\begin{align*}&\cos t=\cos(t+\theta)\iff t=t+\theta\,,\,\,\text{or}\;\;t=-t-\theta\\{}\\
&\sin t=-\sin(t+\theta)\iff t=-t-\theta\;\;or\;\;t=\pi+t+\theta\end{align*}$$

So we can always find a non-zero solution.

Comment: The question is whether this has solutions $z$ for every fixed $\xi$. For quite a few values of $\xi$, it does have (nonzero) solutions.

Comment: The question reads "Does $\bar{z}=\xi z$ has solution in $z$ (complex number) for all values of $\xi \in \mathbb{C}$?", and the answer above shows that it cannot have solution "for all $\;\xi\in\Bbb C\;$ *unless* $\;z=0\;$ . Which proves, and this was supposed to be the OP's self work, that the equation **always** has a solution *for all* $\;\xi\in\Bbb C\;$ , namely $\;z=0\;$ , otherwise $\;|\xi|=1\;$ is a necessary condition.

Comment: Yeah, the question reads that and your answer, while not very clearly formulated, seems to indicate that no $z\ne0$ solves the equation $\bar z=\xi z$, for each given $\xi$. Which is true if $|\xi|\ne1$ but quite wrong if $|\xi|=1$. Let me suggest to reformulate.

Comment: I think you're right, @did: not very clear. I shall edit. Thank you.

Comment: Right. You might want to add the easy fact that if $|\xi|=1$ then indeed there are nonzero solutions $z$.

Comment: Done now...though there's left not much for anyone interested in the problem.

Comment: Maybe the fact that the solutions when $\xi=e^{i\alpha}$ are $z=\pm re^{i\alpha/2}$ is more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, $z=0$ is always a solution and we must have $|\xi|=1$ in order for a nonzero solution $z$ to exist.

To find a solution, consider this: if $|\alpha|=1$ then $\bar{\alpha} = \alpha^{-1}$. Thus
$$\bar z = \xi z \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \xi^{-\frac{1}{2}} \bar z = \xi^{\frac{1}{2}} z \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \overline{\xi^{\frac{1}{2}}z} = \xi^{\frac{1}{2}}z$$
So what can you say about $\xi^{\frac{1}{2}}z$ in relation to $z$ being a solution to $\bar z = \xi z$?